# Drupal site local setup

Tags: drupal

I was trying to set up a drupal site in my local, I have imported the DB and connected it.But when I run my application I got the below error[404 not found error][1]

[https://accesspoint.lndo.site/user/login][1]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you're trying to setup via Lando. It should work without any modifications. Are you following the tutorial correctly? Make sure you don't have any other Drupal-Lando setup with the same name. 
Or do you mean the specific URL (user/login) returns 404?

Comment: Make sure you have run `lando start`. Run `lando info` to make sure the local URL is correct. run `docker ps` to make sure the docker container is running and listening properly.